# Parse HTML with jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose in a variable html is saved like

```
var vhtm="<div><div id='test'>zebra</div><div id='foo'>here is my many other html content</div></div>";
```

i want to parse the above html stored in variable with the help of jquery.
i need to extract a particular div by id and including its content. the return result would like

```
<div id='foo'>here is my many other html content</div>
```

so i need to find div by id like id='foo'

please help me how to parse the above like jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var divHtml = $(vhtm).find("#foo").html();
```

Answer (score 5):

try something like this :

```
$(vhtml).find('#foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the output to contain the whole div including content I'd suggest you use some regular expressions :) Like this maybe:

```
var vhtm="<div><div id='test'>zebra</div><div id='foo'>here is my many other html content</div></div>";
var regex = /<div id='foo'>.*?<\/div>/;
alert(vhtm.match(regex));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I see your point, but my example still works if he's not stuffing his <div id='foo'> with a truckload of complex code ;)

Comment: What about another `<div>` inside that div? Its not 'truckload of complex code', but it'll still break it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any nice way to do that. I would set this as the HTML contents of an DOM element (`$(document.createElement('div')).html(vhtm).find('#foo')`) or create an `about:blank` iframe, add the HTML to it and use `$(iframe.contentWindow.document.body).find(...)` if it requires isolation from the page you're running the script on for some reason

Comment: Note that `$(document.createElement('div'))` is equal to `$('<div />')`.

Comment: It does the same thing, but its [35% slower](http://jsperf.com/jquery-dom-creation-html-vs-createlement). You seriously down-voted the answer because of that?

Comment: Not for that. The solution is overly complicated in this case. The difference seems to be 25 % with the [complete code](http://jsperf.com/parse-html-with-jquery) in favour of the pure jquery version. The performance difference here is largely irrelevant though.

Comment: It's often about readability, and maintainability - both are valid, but I think, provided you're only doing it one, then the string method is preferable. But +1 for the js performance proof.

Comment: I have something along the lines of `$.c=function(tagName, attrs, text) { return $(document.createElement(tagName)).attr(attrs||{}).text(text||''); }` (without the useless calls to `attrs()` and `text()` when there are no arguments, but does the same thing) to make it more readable. I find that even more readable than plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/Vpa3q/

```
var vhtml="<div><div id='test'>zebra</div><div id='foo'>here is my many other html content</div></div>";

var foo = $(vhtml).find('#foo').html();

alert(foo);
```